# Calculate last weeks returning customers DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have googled a lot on this question and tried several things. I want to figure out **how many returning customers we had last week** and compare it with this week. Week to date is functioning.

MY latest code I tried was this:

```
Lastweeksales = CALCULATE([Total returning customers],
FILTER(ALL(orders),
orders[Weeknumber] = SELECTEDVALUE(orders[Weeknumber]) -1))
```

"Total returning customers" is just a sum of all returning customers = "Yes".

I believe what I have to do is to do some kind of summation of "Yes" in each week number, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Can you add some sample data with your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this.

```
Lastweek = 
CALCULATE([Total returning customers],
orders[Weeknumber] = WEEKNUM(TODAY(),2) -1)
```